# How do fix this error:"Cannot invoke getFirst() on the primitive type char"?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, char

I'm an amateur programmer and I'm trying to create a method in java that would allow me to return all the contents of an arraylist that have the same initial for their first name. With my code like this, I keep getting the error, "Cannot invoke getFirst() on the primitive type char" and I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help with this error or show me a differnt way of doing it?

Here's my initial method:

```
public Phonebook findInitial(char p) {
        Phonebook in = new Phonebook();
        for(Phonebook p1:phone)
            if(p.getFirst().charAt(0)==p1.getFirst().charAt(0)) {
                in.add(p1);
                }
        return in;
    }
```

Here's my getter method.

```
public String getFirst() {return first;}
```

Comment: what are you getting from p.getFirst().charAt? That's a char already.

Comment: Welcome. Consider using IDEs like Eclipse, it helps us from syntactical errors, it would have not let you use p.getFirst(); you are not returning an array list in the method and in.add() is not possible unless you have defined it in the Phonebook class. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

`p` is a `char`, so in order to compare it with the first character of `p1.getFirst()`, the condition should be:

```
if (p == p1.getFirst().charAt(0))
```